# Use JSSE for CDC to connect to SSL web site but InvalidKeySpecException(Unknown key spec) occur

Tags: ssl, java-me

I have a java program that is in Windows Mobile 6, and I use CrE-ME™ v4.12 jvm to run the program. Java version is 1.3 with JSSE 1.0.3 for CDC 1.0.2.

I use following code to connect to a secure site.
(This website is using Comodo Free SSL Certificate: 2048-bit, 128/256 bit encryption)

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com/");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

When I try to get the OutputStream

```
OutputStream outStream = conn.getOutputStream();
```

Following error occurs:

```
java.io.IOException: subject key, java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unknown key spec.
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>()
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage()
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record()
...
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `https://some.website.com/` - what is the real URL? `website.com` is a *real* website owned by someone. If you need an example domain, then you should use `example.com`. Its reserved by IANA for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I have already changed it.